# d3: Adding links to nodes in hierarchical edge bundling

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, hyperlink, bundle-layout

I'm a super beginner to d3/HTML/JS and I had a question about adding links to nodes in a graph. All of my code is based on: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7607999

[image]

I'd like to add a link that leads to another html file for each node. Is that possible given how the code is structured?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow - you're expected to post your code

Comment: My JS code is essentially identical to the link I posted. Do you think I should post the relevant parts of the code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to achieve this:

```
node = node
    .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
  .enter()
  .append('a')
    .attr("xlink:href", 'http://www.google.com' /*function(d){return d.url;}*/)
  .append("text")
    .attr("class", "node")
    ...
```

I commented out code that would make the link based on data (i.e. you would have an url field in your input data).

Per request, example of url in data:

```
"children": [
{
    "name": "John Doe",
            "size": 1458,
            "url":  "http://www.johndoe.com"
            ...
```

Comment: That works! I had a question though; for the link based on data, what do you mean by url field in input data? Do you mean in the JSON file I read in or?